# How to edit XML file in Windows Phone 7.1 application

Tags: xml, xml-serialization, windows-phone-7.1

I'm trying to save user data to an XML file on a windows phone (7.1).  In this process I open up the existing XML file, insert a new node and then try to save the XML file.  Although the code runs without error in visual studio 2010, the changes are not made to the file.  I suspect that the problem is that the code is saving the file to someplace else.  I tried creating an XMLWriter with the create command of the XDocument with the fill path to the file as an input parameter but the supported version of the System.XML.Linq (2.0.5) in the windows phone system doesn't allow this.

The code is as follows:

```
            public void AddSwimGoal(SwimGoal SG)    
    {
        string FileName = "Data/SwimGoals.xml";
        XDocument Doc = new XDocument();
        Doc = XDocument.Load(@FileName);

        XElement Root = Doc.Root;
        XElement NewSG = new XElement("SwimGoal");
        XAttribute Dist = new XAttribute("Distance", SG.Distance);
        XAttribute MaxTD = new XAttribute("MaxTrainingDistance", SG.MaxTrainingDistance);
        XAttribute ID = new XAttribute("ID", SG.ID);
        XAttribute Name = new XAttribute("Name", SG.Name);
        XAttribute StartDate = new XAttribute("StartDate", SG.StartDate);
        XAttribute EndDate = new XAttribute("EndDate", SG.EndDate);
        XAttribute DesiredTime = new XAttribute("DesiredTime", SG.Desiredtime);
        XAttribute Stroke = new XAttribute("Stroke", SG.Stroke);
        NewSG.Add(Dist, MaxTD, ID, Name, StartDate, EndDate, DesiredTime, Stroke);
        Root.Add(NewSG);
        XmlWriter Wr = Doc.CreateWriter();
        Doc.Save(Wr);
    }
```

Comment: have you tried to reload the xml document that has been saved?

Comment: yes, the document is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used to save my XML to isolated storage.  You might be right in your thought that it is saving it somewhere else.  The following might resolve that issue.

```
                private void saveXML()
                {
                    using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                    {
                        IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = store.OpenFile("myapp.Xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                        _xdoc.Save(stream);
                        stream.Dispose();
                    }
                }
```

Try to change up the way you add elements to your xml file:

```
                            _xdoc = new XDocument(
                                    new XComment("Created " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()),
                                    new XElement("a",
                                    new XElement("b",
                                    new XElement("c", this.tb_vehicleName.Text.ToString(), new XAttribute("id", 123)),
                                    new XElement("d", ""))));
```

Comment: I tried this using "Data/SwimGoals.xml" in place of "myapp.xml" and Doc.Save(stream) in place of _xdoc.Save(stream) received an error message saying that the operation was not permitted on an IsolatedStorageFileStream. This error occurred on the line IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = store.OpenFile(...

Comment: Take out the "Data/"  Just use SwimGoals.xml and see what that does.

Comment: Eliminating the Data/ removes the error message and allows me to save the file. However, when I check the saved file after executing the code, the file is unchanged. I checked the structure of the document before it was saved with the Doc.ToString command and it was as it should have been. Thanks @Jeff V

Comment: It wasn't the solution as I still can't save to a file but thanks for the effort and feel free to figure out why it won't save @Jeff V

Answer (score 0):

I now realize that the reason the file was not saved is that when this work was done it was done on the emulator and at that time when file was saved I would shut down the emulator.  This destroyed the file and was the reason I couldn't find the changes to the file when I opened it. The code for opening the file substituted a blank document with just the root node if it couldn't find the file when the emulator was reopened.